# how to extract accounts under a particular territory in salesforce?

Tags: account, territory

how to extract accounts under a particular territory in salesforce?
can some one provide me the query please if possible.
Is there a way to do it using vlookup and dataloader?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find Territory Id (If it's a hierarchy you will have to find all of them)

   ```
   SELECT Id, Name FROM Territory WHERE Name = '<TerritoryName>'
   ```
2. Find Accounts that have Owners in that Territory

   **Single**

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN (
       SELECT UserId FROM UserTerritory WHERE TerritoryId = '<TerritoryId>'
   )
   ```

   **Multiple**

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN (
       SELECT UserId FROM UserTerritory WHERE TerritoryId IN ('<TerritoryId1>','<TerritoryId2>')
   )
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Reports - folder Territory Management - Create Report - Accounts with Territories`

Filter where `Territory Name = 'myTerritory'`

Run report and Export Details

Answer (score 0):

Below is an algorithm to get the territory for an account:

Algorithm (Pseudo Code):

> > 1) Query AccountShare object where AccountId = Trigger.New (Account
> >     Ids) where RowCause = 'Territory' (Note: If Account has assigned via
> >     Territory Assignment Rules). where RowCause = 'TerritoryManual' (Note:
> >     If Account has assigned via “Manually Assigned Accounts” related list
> >     on Territory detail page or AccountShare record has created in Apex
> >     Code).
>
> 2) Query Group object where Id = AccountShare.UserOrGroupId
>
> 3)Query Territory object where Id = Group.RelatedId
>
> 4) Query UserTerritory object where Id = Territory.UserId.

try this . i found from old [dev post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008w0uIAA)